# Magento 2.3.5 Tracking Email Missing Tracking Number And Order Items

Tags: magento2, email, shipment, magento2.3.5-p1

When sending the tracking email in Magento 2 we are running into some major issues.

Using the default Luma shipment email `{{trans "%name," name=$billing.name}}` This part always comes out as a single comma as if its failed to retrieve the name.

and `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}` this section is always missing from the email.

I added a little bit of logging into the `track.phtml` which is responsible for it and from what I can see `<?php $_shipment = $block->getShipment() ?>` that bit of code always simply returns null, along with ```getOrder() ?>''' .

Since they come back as null the if check never works and they the tracking is never added, what I am wondering is why these would ever be null?

Every other email seems to work fine but for some reason shipping always just finds these 2 fields as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug in 2.3.4 - 2.3.5,

Can be resolved by setting the `is_legacy` field to 1 in the `email_template` table.

Click [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26882) for github issue related to this

Comment: yes, this is working fine..